# Sanitise user input on Koa?

Tags: koa, sanitization, koa2, html-sanitizing

What's a good way to sanitise user input on Koa2?

Would be preferable to use an external sanitisation library rather than roll my own (less prone to vulnerabilities that way).

Answer (score 1):

There's several possible middleware you can look into.

Check out [koa-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-validate) for a barebones validator.

If you want to use something like [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup), check out [koa-yup-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-yup-validator).

If you want to use [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi), check out [koa-joi-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-joi-router).

Really depends on what you're looking for.